# Adding Sibling Nodes to a Nested List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

Given the following markup:

```
<div id="nodes">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Colors</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sizes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Material</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I wrote a jQuery function to add sibling nodes:

```
$("#nodes ul li").click(function(e) {
    addSibling(this, 'new one');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

function addSibling(selector, content){
    var markup='<li><a href="#">' + content + '</a></li>';
    $(selector).parent().append(markup);
}
```

At first it seems to work great, as long as I click on the original nodes. For example, if I click on 'Blue', I get:

```
<div id="nodes">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Colors</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">new node</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sizes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Material</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However when I click on the new node, instead of putting the new nodes as a sibling, it ends up one level up (That is, a sibling of 'Colors', 'Size' and 'Material'). Looking at the markup generated by jQuery, I don't see any difference, so I'm stumped why the new nodes act different from the original ones. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$("#nodes ul").click(function (e) {
    addSibling(e.target, 'new one');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

function addSibling(selector, content) {
    var markup = '<li><a href="#">' + content + '</a></li>';
    $(selector).parent().append(markup);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xv4GF/).

This binds the click-handler to the `ul` elements, and, instead of `this` it uses `e.target`, which is the element that was clicked within the `ul`. This means you avoid the problem of not having bound the click event-handler to newly-added elements.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that jquery registers your click callback to already existing objects. When you click on newly created li it just bubbles up and fires one level higher.

Besides that: you have class="nodes" and you wanted to have id="nodes".

How to fix that? Try registering your click to ul (not li) and in addSibling remove parent.

Answer (score 0):

Since when you add a the new node to the DOM you don't attach a click event to it, the underlying 'li' is registering the click and attaching the node to that. To remedy this, in your addSibling function, after you create the new node, attach a click event to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your newly created `<li>`s don't have an event handler attached to them. That's because when you call `$("#nodes ul li").click(...)` only the elements that fit the selector get the handlers attached to them.  Once that function is called, it will not be called again when new elements get added to the DOM.  As a result, your click on new `<li>`s "bubbles up" until it hits an `<li>` that already has an event handler.

You can fix this problem by using a delegate click handler, rather than one directly on the element:

```
$("#nodes").on("click","li",function(e) {
    addSibling(this, 'new one');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The way this works is as follows:
You attach only one click handler to the `#nodes` element.  When you click on any `<li>` inside the `nodes` element, the function get triggered.  And since it applies to all `<li>`s inside the `#nodes` element, it doesn't matter if they are dynamically created.

Comment: Thanks for the copy and paste solution, but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: That is probably because I copied your JS... and you use an `id` in the JS while you use a class in the HTML.  So either change the JS to `$(".nodes")` or the HTML to `id="nodes"`

Comment: I edited the selector in your code to match my markup, and it still didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I mixed up my parameters... ooops... the code above is now correct. (the `"click"` and the `"li"` were reversed before)

Comment: I went and tried it, but clicking on 'Red', for example, gives you two new nodes instead of one.